# tizen delta and project files

Tags: file, sdk, tizen

What does the xml `.project` and `.cproject` file contains ?

`.rds_delta` is a file which contains data like

`#delete
 .delta.lst
 #add
 #modify
 author-signature.xml
 signature1.xml`

what is it's purpose?

There is another file `.sdk_delta.info` what does this contains

I would like to know the consequences of change in these file (each of these files).

Answer (score 2):

You typically wouldn't change any of these files manually.

The `.project` file contains general settings for your project. Eclipse settings, whether the project is linked to another project, etc.

The `.cproject` contains C/C++-specific settings for your project. Build paths, build flags, which compiler to use, etc.

Comment: @Micheal thanks for your answer, What about those delta files